# angular JavaScript not working in children component, javascript file not loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a left side navigation in home component, the navigation dropdown is not working in one of the routing module (**admin-routing.module.ts**).
the navigation is working in **app-routing.module.ts** "path:'home'"
the component file is same in the two routing modules

i am new in angular, i am using angular 14v

i have a component name with "home"

i used two routing

1. **app-routing.module.ts**
2. **admin-routing.module.ts**

This goes inside **app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes =
  [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent },
    { path: 'not-found', component: NotFoundComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
      path: 'admin',
      loadChildren: () =>
        import('./modules/admin/admin.module').then((m) => m.AdminModule)
    },
    {path:'home', component:HomeComponent},
    { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },
    
  ];
```

This goes inside **admin-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

i also added the script file path in **angular.json**

the navigation dropdown and toogle is not working in **admin-routing.module.ts**'s "home path"

i hosted these files in my server

working navigation link is http://angular.byteinnovations.in/home

this navigation is not working  http://angular.byteinnovations.in/admin/home

Comment: On which server you have deployed angular applications? Depends on your server, you have to do some configuration on server so that static pages will serve without any issues.